# Programmatically serialize class to xsd

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

Is there a way to create an XSD from a C# .NET class programmatically? I want to serialize objects to xsd (or xml) with type information.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes; look at `XsdDataContractExporter`; MSDN has a [full example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.xsddatacontractexporter.aspx).

Alternative; [`XmlSchemaExporter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlschemaexporter.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

This should give you the types as well! (if you are looking for xml solution, for xsd solution, Marc has the answer ;-))

```
var oEmp = new Emp { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith", DOJ = DateTime.Today };
            using (var stream = File.Create("J:\\XML\\Employee.xml"))
            {
                var sri = new SoapReflectionImporter();
                var xtm = sri.ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Emp));
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(xtm);
                serializer.Serialize(stream, oEmp);
            }
```

The output XML...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Emp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
  <FirstName xsi:type="xsd:string">John</FirstName>
  <LastName xsi:type="xsd:string">Smith</LastName>
  <DOJ xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">2011-11-29T00:00:00+01:00</DOJ>
</Emp>
```