# Create XSD for class structure

Tags: xsd

I would like to describe this class structure by XSD but I couldnt find any solution:

```
public class A {
 string property { get; }
 B[] property2 { get; }//occurs 0 to unbound
}


public class B {
 string property { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i think, the following XML schema will help you solve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Class" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/Class" elementFormDefault="qualified">


<element name="A" type="tns:A"></element>

<simpleType name="property">
    <restriction base="string"></restriction>
</simpleType>

<complexType name="B">
    <sequence>
        <element name="property" type="tns:property"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="A">
    <sequence>
        <element name="property" type="tns:property"></element>
        <element name="B" type="tns:B" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"></element>
    </sequence>
</complexType>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C# take a look at this question/answer :

[Programatically serialize class to xsd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308500/programatically-serialize-class-to-xsd)

But the problem when serializing to XSD is that `DataMember` attributes have serious limitations for XSD (see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/e95ba78b-9932-4d8a-91ac-6b40967d0d8b).

So, maybe you can generate your XSD by serialization and perform some custom modifications, essentially for data constraints (length, ranges, min/max...)

**[Edit]** Or if you want to do it by yourself take a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/schema/